# unable to add pdo_mysql to PHP Modules although i have modified php.ini file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii, php-ini

`php -m [PHP Modules] bcmath calendar Core ctype date dom filter hash iconv json libxml mysqlnd pcre PDO Phar readline Reflection session SimpleXML SPL standard tokenizer xml xmlreader xmlwriter zip zlib`

this is my list of modules that cause PDOException i want to change adding pdo_mysql.

i have already unchecked 'extension=pdo_mysql', i have simple mysql server.

I haven't found any answer that resolve my problem, so what i have to do now?

note: php_ini_loaded_file() returns me null

Comment: Run `php --ini` to see what file it's loading. Note it's likely that there are different ini files for CLI and for FPM/CGI/Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved creating new php.ini file and paste all the content of the old file.